# how does cobegin work?

Tags: concurrency

I don't know how do concurrent processes work? for example what is the output of this program maybe occur?

```
void main()
{
 a = 0;
 cobegin { p(); p(); }
}
const int n = 50;
int a;
int i;
void P()
{
for ( i=1; i<=n; i++) a++;
print ( a );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988055/maximum-and-minimum-value-of-cobegin-coend-block) about concurrent loops with a shared counter which modify a shared variable. Difference in languages (your question seems to be about C, referenced one is about Pascal) is not important, as `cobegin` is mainly a *concept*.